# How can we find out the reasons for an Area 51 discussion being deleted?

Tags: support, area-51, deleted-questions

How can we find out the reasons for [Translation proposals - one-on-one, or free-for-all?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/translation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all) being silently deleted?

(Maybe the general question extends to any kind of page deletion, but I'd really like to know the reasons in this precise case.)

Comment: You can view an older copy of the page using [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdiscuss.area51.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F272%2Ftranslation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all). I don't see any good reason for it to be deleted, myself -- possibly the author did it. "Reasons of moderation" is inaccurate in that case, and one of my pet peeves.

Comment: @Matthew That's why the OP deleting a question won't say "reasons of moderation", it'll say ["voluntarily removed by its author"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73294/migrated-comments-should-have-correct-display-names)

Comment: @Michael Ooh, in that case I found a bug. Now to go about reproducing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we find out the reasons for an Area 51 discussion being deleted?

Find a moderator or someone with 10k or more on Area51 and ask them.

Regarding the discussion in particular:

It was marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and then immediately deleted by [Dori](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2559/dori) on 11 August 2011.

It was not closed prior to deletion, so I cannot guess at the reason.

Comment: Ok, so this must be the answer to the general question.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR version**: I've [re-opened it](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/translation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all).

---

Of the six proposals mentioned in the January 31 [Translation proposals - one-on-one, or free-for-all?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/translation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all) question, two have been closed as duplicates. The remaining four are:

- [Russian Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language-usage)
- [Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16613/languages)
- [Translation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4306/translation)
- [Portuguese Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26339/portuguese-language-usage)

The majority of the question is about whether there should be multiple sites for a single given language, and if so, how they should work.

For instance, at one point there were three different French proposals: [English/French Translation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation), [Le bon usage du français [French usage]](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16870/le-bon-usage-du-francais-french-usage), and [French Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage). There were also two Russian proposals, two Spanish proposals, etc.—a clearly unworkable situation. This has since been straightened out, and there are now only "Language & Usage" sites and proposals.

This main part is what I closed as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), as having multiple sites per language has been hashed, re-hashed, and a decision made. That itself would have been sufficient, but it didn't help that the discussion was inactive from February 24 to July 31. <sub>(An answer was added on July 31 which received a comment on August 7, but neither introduced new points, and really should have been on more specific discussions—see below.)</sub>

The remainder of the question is about the Languages and Translation proposals and can they/how should they work—all of which are covered by these already-existing discussions:

- [Languages: Should we allow questions in any language?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/languages-should-we-allow-questions-in-any-language)
- [Should the "Languages" site include in its scope what is covered by the "Language & Usage" sites for languages unlikely to get their own site?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/should-the-languages-site-include-in-its-scope-what-is-covered-by-the-language)
- [Merging All the Language Proposals into one language website](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/merging-all-the-language-proposals-into-one-language-website)
- [Should the Translation proposal be closed for being too broad?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/should-the-translation-proposal-be-closed-for-being-too-broad)

I don't know what issues (if any) are still open at [Translation proposals - one-on-one, or free-for-all?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/translation-proposals-one-on-one-or-free-for-all). I also don't believe that it's the appropriate place for those issues to be discussed, and I recommend taking anything left undecided to the more specific discussions. However, since there seems to be an interest in continuing a discussion there, I've reopened it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, all this makes sense. Though, I don't understand how deletion could be appropriate. I was looking for some information and couldn't find this thread from my profile. I think that just closing it (and providing some short explanation for that) should be enough?