# Implement "reasons" to delete answers much like vote to close reasons

Tags: feature-request, answers, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “Delete with reason” button/dialog to existing moderator tools for flagged answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116762/add-delete-with-reason-button-dialog-to-existing-moderator-tools-for-flagged-a)

There was a feature request to [add reasons for deletion for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29871/add-delete-reasons-like-we-have-close-reasons), but this isn't that.

My feature request is as follows:

Add Reasons to delete in a dialog box when a user clicks on 'delete' for an *answer*.  This would require every user who votes to delete (or moderators) to use one of the predetermined reasons:

- Not an answer
- Spam
- Does not address the question

Once the answer has reached the threshold, the deletion reason would be displayed as well as a blurb that links to the FAQ on how to get it undeleted *much like the close blurb already works*.

This would be in line with allowing the community to police itself, and make sure arbitrary deletions aren't happening, as well as to give the person whose post was deleted an idea of *why* it was deleted.

The review queue can already do this, but it isn't tied in to the actual answer page.  Clicking on 'delete' on an answer will bypass this (at least for moderators).

This feature request stems [from my answer to a relevant question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155765/16587) on this topic.

Comment: How's "Not an answer" different from "Does not address the question"? Also this could tell people if the answer was converted to a comment, something like "Not an answer (converted to comment)".

Comment: Currently, I see a lot of 20k users deleting downvoted wrong answers (that are actually answers). Is this even encouraged?

Comment: @YannisRizos I was thinking that something could be 'not an answer' (it could be a question, or a comment), or it could be an answer (it's not a question or a comment) but it does not address the question asked. They are closely related (and you could say they're exactly the same) but there is a nuance there.  I wouldn't be adverse to having better verbiage and combining the two.

Comment: @Mysticial my impression is it's not bad if users do it, but it's something moderators shouldn't have to police. Correctness = community, approprietness= moderation

Comment: @YannisRizos I had a couple of NaA flags declined on answers that did not address the question. But they could have been legitimate (if somewhat poor) answers to different questions. I guess if I had a "Doesn't address the question" option, they wouldn't have been declined.

Comment: @random My question gets into something the other question waited until the very end to address: This should be a requirement for to close a question, and it should be available to everyone who can vote to delete.